# List Of Listings Overlapping Text

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, listings

I'm attempting to generate a list of listings for my dissertation. The university doesn't have a standard LaTeX template, but there is a pretty good one generated sometime ago that does the trick. The only problem is that it did not include a List of Listings function, so I went ahead and modified the definition for the List of Figures (shown below) to define a new List of Listings.

```
% LIST OF TABLES
%
% Single-space list of tables, add it to the table of contents.
\def\listoftables{%
  \@restonecolfalse%
  \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\fi%
  \newpage%
  \centerline{\expandafter\uppercase\expandafter{\listtablename}}%
  \bigskip%
  \phantomsection%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{frontmatter}{\protect\numberline{}\listtablename }%
  % This group overloads \numberline to output ``Table 1.3'' instead of ``1.3''
  \begingroup%
    \let\ORIG@numberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{\ORIG@numberline{\tablename~##1:}}%
    {\ssp\@starttoc{lot}}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi%
  \endgroup %
  }

\newlength{\@tablelength}
\settowidth{\@tablelength}{\tablename }
% Magic value, but consistent with the standard table length.
\addtolength{\@tablelength}{2.8em}
\def\l@table{\normalfont\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{\@tablelength}}
```

This is what I came up with ...

```
% LIST OF LISTINGS
%
% Single-space list of listings, add it to the table of contents.

\def\listoflistings{%
  \@restonecolfalse%
  \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\fi%
  \newpage%
  \centerline{\expandafter\uppercase\expandafter{\listlistingname}}%
  \bigskip%
  \phantomsection%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{frontmatter}{\protect\numberline{}\listlistingname }%
  %This group overloads \numberline to output ``Source Code 1.3'' instead of ``1.3''
  \begingroup%
    \let\ORIG@numberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{\ORIG@numberline{\listingname~##1:}}%
    {\ssp\@starttoc{lol}}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi%
  \endgroup %
  }

\newlength{\@listinglength}
\settowidth{\@listinglength}{\listingname }
% Magic value, but consistent with the standard listing length
\addtolength{\@listinglength}{2.8em}
\def\l@listing{\normalfont\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{\@listinglength}}
```

The only problem is that the text `\listingname` (Source Code) and the short caption for the listing are overlapping (see below), when they shouldn't be (see example of List of Figures below).

[image]

[image]

I believe I have identified that the problem stems from how the .lot and .lol files are being generated, namely the .lol file is missing the keyword `\ignorespaces`.

.lot FILE

```
\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax 
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {2.S1}{\ignorespaces Pedigree 1 Candidate Variants}}{33}{table.2.1}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {2.S2}{\ignorespaces Pedigree 2 Candidate Variants}}{33}{table.2.2}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {3.1}{\ignorespaces Variants identified.}}{43}{table.3.1}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {3.S1}{\ignorespaces Capture and Variant Calling Statistics.}}{44}{table.3.1}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {3.S2}{\ignorespaces Variant Filtering Statistics.}}{44}{table.3.2}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {3.S3}{\ignorespaces Primers.}}{45}{table.3.3}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {3.S4}{\ignorespaces Candidate variants.}}{46}{table.3.4}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {3.S5}{\ignorespaces Novel SNVs identified at a high rate in the Pakistani population.}}{47}{table.3.5}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {4.1}{\ignorespaces Dual index y-adaptors}}{64}{table.4.1}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {4.S1}{\ignorespaces SNVs used for homozygosity mapping}}{74}{table.4.1}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {A.1}{\ignorespaces Example Read Depth Functions.}}{145}{table.A.1}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\addvspace {10\p@ }
```

.lol FILE

```
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {B.1}annotateVariants.cpp}{157}{lstlisting.B.1}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {B.2}macPC.h}{200}{lstlisting.B.2}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {B.3}patterns.h}{200}{lstlisting.B.3}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {B.4}patterns.cpp}{200}{lstlisting.B.4}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {B.5}genomeCDNAProtein.h}{207}{lstlisting.B.5}
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {B.6}genomeCDNAProtein.cpp}{208}{lstlisting.B.6}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `listings` package or at least `tocloft` for easy generation of such `list of something` stuff?

Comment: I am using the listings package, however; for uniformity with the List of Figures and List of Tables in the dissertation I've tried to adapt their commands to my needs.

Comment: Are there any news here? Maybe @christian has an idea?

Comment: @Johannes_B: I'l look later on, now shopping for the weeking ;-)